# How to mock/test logger which reports Exception?

Tags: python, logging, mocking

Could anyone of you explain why the following `assert_called_with` doesn't work, please?

According to the information printed by pytest 'Expected call' equals 'Actual call', so I assume that some information is lost when pytest converts it to str to print it on terminal.

What tool would you recommend to debug it?

Program:

```
import logging
from mock import patch

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

def func():
    try:
        raise ValueError("error XYZ")
    except ValueError as err:
        logger.error(err)

def test_func():
    with patch('logging.Logger.error') as log:
        func()
        log.assert_called_with(ValueError("error XYZ"))
```

Execution:

```
$ pytest prog.py
=========================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.15+, pytest-4.2.0, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1
rootdir: /tmp, inifile:
collected 1 item

prog.py F                                                                                                                                                           [100%]

================================================================================ FAILURES =================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________ test_func ________________________________________________________________________________

    def test_func():
        with patch('logging.Logger.error') as log:
            func()
>           log.assert_called_with(ValueError("error XYZ"))

prog.py:16:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/home/ebajgrz/py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py:937: in assert_called_with
    six.raise_from(AssertionError(_error_message(cause)), cause)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

value = AssertionError("Expected call: error(ValueError('error XYZ',))\nActual call: error(ValueError('error XYZ',))",), from_value = None

    def raise_from(value, from_value):
>       raise value
E       AssertionError: Expected call: error(ValueError('error XYZ',))
E       Actual call: error(ValueError('error XYZ',))

/home/ebajgrz/py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py:737: AssertionError
======================================================================== deprecated python version ========================================================================
You are using Python 2.7.15, which will no longer be supported in pytest 5.0
For more information, please read:
  https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/py27-py34-deprecation.html
======================================================================== 1 failed in 0.28 seconds ============================
```

I realize that pytest has caplog and it's possible to implement test as follows, but I'd like to understand why the first method doesn't work.

```
def test_func2(caplog):
    func()
    assert 'error XYZ' in caplog.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `mock` is checking the object that's passed in against the object that's expected. They're different objects, so the assertion fails. For instance, open up a python shell and try this:

```
>>> ValueError('bees') == ValueError('bees')
False
```

They're not equal because they're different objects. But try this:

```
>>> str(ValueError('bees')) == str(ValueError('bees'))
True
```

This is because strings are immutable. Now, if you change your original log call to be this: `logger.error(str(err))` and change your assertion to be: `log.assert_called_with(str(ValueError("error XYZ")))`, I think you'll get past that first error.

Unrelated to that, and more of a suggestion for logging exceptions: you may want to log more info in an except block like that. Something like this:

```
logger.error('Error raised doing something: %s', str(err), exc_info=True)
```